# How to get ExtendedFloatingActionButton to behave similar to FloatingActionButton when interacting with CoordinatorLayout and scrolling?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components, coordinator-layout

Trying to use the new `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`. It seems by default `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` acts differently from `FloatingActionButton` when interacting with `CoordinatorLayout`. See here the red one is the typical `FloatingActionButton` and the 2 black ones are the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` with exactly the same setup (except for colors and text).
What I need is for the black ones to hide away just like the red one does.

[image: Text]

Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/exfab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"
        app:strokeColor="#ffff00"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp"
        app:iconTint="#ffff00"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/exfab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:strokeColor="#ffff00"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp"
        app:iconTint="#ffff00"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I see in source that there's a nested class `ExtendedFloatingActionButton.ExtendedFloatingActionButtonBehavior` and it seems to have maybe some properties that might be useful/related to this such as `autoHideEnabled` and `autoShrinkEnabled` but the class is protected and I can't figure out how it is meant to be accessed.
Please help.

Comment: I've opened an issue on [github for this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/880). The enhancement is [being worked on it seems](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/883).